# onclick event not firing after onchange event

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to make a simple JavaScript `onclick` event fire if the process of clicking the element causes an onchange event to fire elsewhere on the page? I've created a very simple page to demonstrate this problem:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="test" id="test1" onchange="return change(event);" />
        <a href="#" id="test2" onclick="return bang();">Bang</a>
        <a href="#" id="test3" onclick="return boom();">Boom</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function change(event) {
                alert("Change");
                return true;
            }

            function bang() {
                alert("Bang!");
                return true;
            }

            function boom() {
                alert("Boom!");
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you click the bang link you get the Bang! alert. Boom gives you the Boom alert. And if you enter text in the text field and tab out you get the Change alert. All well and good.

However, if you enter text in the text field and, without tabbing or clicking anything else first, click either Bang or Boom you get the Change alert and nothing else. I would expect to see the Change alert followed by either Bang or Boom.

What's going on here? My change event returns true. How can I ensure that my click event is fired?

Comment: Tip: create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ and share it here. This makes it easier for people to test it out and help.

Comment: You should probably use addEventListener rather than assign them via the html as a side tip.

Comment: Try with `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `alert()` function grabs the event chain somehow, test this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test1" onchange="return change(event);" />
    <a href="#" id="test2" onclick="return bang();">Bang</a> <a href="#" id="test3" onclick="return boom();">Boom</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change(event) {
          console.log("change");
            return true;
        }  

        function bang() {
            console.log("bang");
            return true;
        }

        function boom() {
            console.log("boom");
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

As you'll see you'll get the expected behaviour in the console.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eruvox/2/edit)

Answer (score 5):

Okay... So it seems like it's *time* for a bit of an explanation.

**Explanation**

You encounter this error because the `onchange` event is triggered as soon as focus is moved away from the element. In your example the action that takes focuse away from the `input` element is the `mousedown` event which triggers as you *click down on the mouse*. This means that when you `mousedown` on the link it fires off the `onchange` function and pops up the alert.

The `onclick` event on the other hand is triggered on the `mouseup` event (i.e. when you release the pressure on the mouse - prove this to yourself by `click, hold/pause, release` on a `onlcick` event). Back to your situation... Before the `mouseup` (i.e. `onclick`) happens the focus is moved to the `alert` triggered from your `onchange` function.

**Fix**

There are a couple of options to fix this. Most simple change from using `onclick="...."` to `onmousedown="...."`.

Alternatively, you could use `setTimeout` like,:

```
function change() {
    setTimeout(function (){
        alert("Change event")
    }, 100)
}
```

I suggest the `onmousedown` method as preferred. The `setTimeout` method will fail if you *click and hold* on the link for more than the prescribed amount on the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try and replicate your problem, I just created the solution in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sqpd/1/).

I seperated your HTML and your JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" />
<a href="#" id="test2">Bang</a> 
<a href="#" id="test3">Boom</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1");
var test2 = document.getElementById("test2");
var test3 = document.getElementById("test3");

test1.onchange = function (event) {
    alert("Change");
};

test2.onclick = function () {
    alert("Bang!");
};

test3.onclick = function () {
    alert("Boom!");
};
```

After making a change in the text box and click out side of it will trigger the `onchange` event, and the `onclick` events will still fire.  If you are expecting the change alert to fire for each key stroke change `onchange` to `onkeyup`.

Comment: You have recreated the problem... This code has the same flaw as the original that was posted by the asker.

Comment: @Steven Then I don't really see what the flaw is, unless it is browser specific.  Because with Chrome I don't have any issues.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained. The problem that he is having is that when you type something into the input field and then _immediately_ click on one of the links (i.e. before tabbing out of the `input` or clicking anywhere else on the page) the `onclick` event doesn't fire (when there is an `alert(...)` in the `onchange` event of the `input`). Your code relies on having already changed focus from the `input` before clicking the text link. (There is a chance this behaviour doesn't occur in your browser... I've tested with FF an Chromium. **Fix** would be to change to `onmousedown` (see above)

Answer (score 0):

Just DO One Trick and bang!!!!

```
var isTest2ButtonClicked=false;
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1");
var test2 = document.getElementById("test2");
var test3 = document.getElementById("test3");

test1.onchange = function (event) {
    alert("Change");
    if(isTest2ButtonClicked)
    {
        //fire onclick event of test 2 button
        $('#test2').click();
    }
};

test2.onclick = function () {
    alert("Bang!");
};
test2.onmousedown= function () {
    isTest2ButtonClicked=true;
};
test3.onclick = function () {
    alert("Boom!");
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).